# Want to Implement Timeout for one function in C

Tags: c

Here i have one function which is listen mode. this function listing something which i got form some device.

Here when my function is in listen mode that time i want to create timeout. if i will not get any response from particular device than i want o exit from this function and have to notify.

if during this timeout period if i will get response from device than i have to continue with work and stop this timeout and there is no limits to complete this work in any time duration.

So how can i implement this thing for a function.

Any body please can me help me to implement this thing with timeout functionality.

Comment: I think the only sane way to do this is to start a separate processes, which you then kill if it takes too long. It is very hard to "stop" code that is running inside your process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `man 2 alarm`. You can set or disable signals which will be sent to your application after a certain time period elapses.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you are waiting for a response from this device, the answer to your question will be different. The basic framework is:

```
int do_something_with_device()
{
    if (!wait_for_response_from_device()) {
        return TIMEOUT_ERROR;
    }
    // continue with processing
}
```

As for how you implement `wait_for_response_from_device()`, well, every device is different. If you're using sockets or pipes, use `select()`. If you're interfacing with something that requires a busy-wait loop, it might look like:

```
int wait_for_response_from_device()
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) - start < TIMEOUT) {
        if (check_device_ready()) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Naturally, the implementation of `check_device_ready()` would be up to you.

Comment: Here i have one function which put my device in listen mode , because my device is ready to receive file from any device through bluetooth. here i am using obex_test library for this

Comment: After some time if i am not getting response form remote device means (any mobile device) than i have to disconnect this and notify my server